# Mule - How to respond after receiving a request collection. (Mule Requester )

Tags: exception, collections, ftp, mule, anypoint-studio

I am using the Mule Requestor to receive a collection of files via FTP.

[image: Request FTP file collection retrieval]

In order to do this with a collection I am using the Collection Splitter which works great.  The only problem is that when I am returning to the HTTP Connector it throws the following exception:

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: getPayloadAsBytes(), use
>   getPayload(DataType.BYTE_ARRAY_DATA_TYPE)

I am guessing this has something to do with the payload type that is trying to be inserted into the response, but I am fairly new in the Mule arena.  Any idea what could be causing this and what I should do to resolve the issue?

I have tried setting the payload after the logger, that didn't work.

Code:

```
<flow name="fileGetter">     
  <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/test" doc:name="HTTP" allowedMethods="GET"></http:listener>
  <mulerequester:request-collection config-ref="Mule_Requester" resource="ftp_For_Requester_Dependent" doc:name="Mule Requester</mulerequester:request-collection>  
  <collection-splitter doc:name="Collection Splitter"></collection-splitter>
  <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message="#[message.inboundProperties.originalFilename]"></logger>  
</flow>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are getting `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: getPayloadAsBytes(), use getPayload(DataType.BYTE_ARRAY_DATA_TYPE)` is obvious, since you are splitting the payload, at the end your HTTP in causing the issue as there will be a split response .
One solution would be, use an **aggregator** at the end of your flow and that will prevent this exception.
A `<collection-aggregator/>` at the end will be a good choice and help to prevent this

**UPDATE**
Keep it under `<async>` block and it will run successfully

Comment: Unfortunately thats not what is causing the exception.  I have already added the collection aggregator and I get the exact same exception.

Comment: Try keeping it under async block

Comment: AHH! Anir, thank you! That worked great.... would you mind explaining why that worked?  I am still pretty new to Mule.

Comment: yes, as I already mentioned that since you are splitting the payload, the payload is getting split and causing trouble in HTTP endpoint at the end at the point of response. So, I suggested to aggregate the payload at the end.. now since you said, it's not working, so I suggested to use `<async>` as an alternate solution. This `<async>` will be one way and doesn't care for response .. so the HTTP endpoint are not troubled at the end with split payload .. I have updated my answer accordingly .. If it worked for you could you or you found useful pls accept the answer then

Comment: Yes, the inline <async> block did the trick.  The only downside to this, is that you any variable manipulation is obviously lost in the process, but I was able to work around this in the flow.  Thanks for the explanation!